# Testable random number generator

Tags: c#

Here is a custom `Random<T>` class which could be used as:

```
Random<int> random = Random<int>(10);
int zeroToTen = random.Next();
```

I also made it seedable through the ambient context, so the following is observed allowing to potentially have `Seed` anywhere above in the call stack to simplify unit testing:

```
Random<int> Numbers { get; } = new Random<int>(10);

[TestMethod]
public void Seed_With_Seed_Value()
{
    int[] a, b;
    using (new Seed("Numbers", 33))
        a = new[] { Numbers.Next(), Numbers.Next(), Numbers.Next(), Numbers.Next() };
    using (new Seed("Numbers", 33))
        b = new[] { Numbers.Next(), Numbers.Next(), Numbers.Next(), Numbers.Next() };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual( a, b);            
}

[TestMethod]
public void Seed_With_Sequence()
{
    using (new Seed("Numbers") { 1, 2, 3 })
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, Numbers.Next());
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Numbers.Next());
        Assert.AreEqual(3, Numbers.Next());
    }
}
```

where library code is:

```
public class Random<T> 
{
    public Random(T max, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        Max = max;
        Name = name;
    }

    T Max { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    public T Next() =>
        (T)Convert.ChangeType(
            Seed.Of(Name).Next(Convert.ToDouble(Max)),
            typeof(T));
}
```

and:

```
public class Seed : IEnumerable, IDisposable
{
    static AsyncLocal<Seed> Context { get; } = new AsyncLocal<Seed>();
    static Seed Default { get; } = new Seed();
    public static Seed Of(string name)
    {
        for (var c = Context.Value; c != null; c = c.Parent)
            if (c.Name == name)
                return c;

        return Default;
    }

    Seed()
    {
        Value = null;
        Sequence = new ConcurrentQueue<double>();
        Random = new Random();
    }

    public Seed(string name, int? value = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Parent = Context.Value;
        Context.Value = this;
        Sequence = new ConcurrentQueue<double>();
        Random = value == null
            ? new Random() 
            : new Random(value.Value);
    }

    public void Dispose() => Context.Value = Parent;

    Seed Parent { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    int? Value { get; }
    ConcurrentQueue<double> Sequence { get; }
    Random Random { get; }
    public void Add(double next) => Sequence.Enqueue(next);
    public double Next(double max) =>
        Sequence.TryDequeue(out var value) ? value : 
        Random.NextDouble() * max;            

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() =>
        Sequence.GetEnumerator();
}
```